# Nginx: HowTo rewrite nonx-existing .php file to index.php?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, location

Below you see the part of my server which works brilliant, but now i have to "simulate" a php file which does not exists.

```
location ~ \.php$
{ 
 fastcgi_pass php;
 include fastcgi.conf;
}

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
```

All my urls are currently rewritten du the try_files setting to my index.php, but not if i try to access domain.tld/something.php.

How can i make those location block/s make `domain.tld/something**.php**` to use my `try_files` and send it to `index.php`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine for me. Hope this will work for you as well.

```
location ~\.php$ {
    index index.php index.html;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files /index.php /index.php;
}
```

Comment: Awesome ;), just try_files inside the .php location made it!
Thank you!